# Curl - Does not work on Windows CLI

Tags: curl, php

Curl would not work on windows Command Prompt but it working fine on the browser (localhost)

Error:

```
C:\wamp\www\site>C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe -f index.php

PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\site\index.php on line 111

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init() in C:\wamp\www\site\index.php on line 111
```

Yes PHP Curl is enabled, like I said it work fine on the browser.

Comment: Not directly related to your problem but PHP 5.3.0 is ancient. You should use 5.3.6!

Comment: @ThiefMaster Indeed I need upgrade wamp.

Answer (score 6):

Run **php -r "echo php_ini_loaded_file();"** in the command line to see which ini file is being loaded.

Then remove the **;** before **extension=php_curl.dll** around line 656

Restart apache

For this to work, make sure php is set as global variable, if not got to D:\wamp\bin\php\php5.2.5 (*path can change on ur computer*) from the command line & run the code

Answer (score 5):

Try running

```
php.exe --re curl
```

to make sure curl is enabled/available for php-cli, too. Make sure that cli uses the same php.ini as the one in your webserver, otherwise it might be necessary to enable curl there, too.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue just now this this - after installing PEAR.

There was a php.ini in

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8
```

But the one used by Apache was located in

```
C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin
```

Answer (score 3):

Do a:

```
php.exe -i > phpinfo.txt
```

Open `phpinfo.txt` and check:

1. Loaded Configuration File
2. extension_dir
3. Loaded extensions

More than likely, PHP-CLI is loading a different `.ini` file.

## Edit

Well, seems like you can do a:

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.exe -c C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0\php.ini -f index.php
```

Inside the `-c` parameter, specify path of the `.ini` file you wish to use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the same goes for Windows based platforms, but under Linux the CLI PHP executable (Command Prompt runnable binary) uses a different `php.ini` than the webserver binary (probably the CGI module under Windows).

Looks to me as if the Curl module is enabled in the webserver `php.ini`, but not in the CLI version.